# problem building and installing geary

Tags: installation, geary

I'm using ubuntu 12.10 and I'd like to install geary 0.2.2.
When I type ./configure, it shows:

```
peng@peng-ThinkPad-SL410:~/Downloads/geary-0.2.2$ ./configure

cmake version 2.8.9

-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Icon cache will be updated
-- Desktop database will be updated
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26") 
-- xgettext found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Vala (missing: VALA_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindVala.cmake:55 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:269 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Unable to prepare build directory.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

KEY -> Could NOT find Vala (you need to install vala)

**Building & Running**

To fetch a copy of the source from Yorba's git repository:

```
$ git clone git://yorba.org/geary
```

Geary requires Vala 0.17.4 (or higher) and cmake. It also requires the developer packages (headers) for the following packages:

```
canberra
gee-1.0
gio-2.0
glib-2.0
gmime-2.6
gnome-keyring-1
gtk+-3.0
notify
sqlite3
unique-3.0
webkitgtk-3.0
indicate (optional; enables support for Ubuntu Unity messaging menu)
unity (optional; enables support for Ubuntu Unity launcher)
```

Most of these are standard libraries available from major distros' repositories.

On Ubuntu 12.04, you can install Vala 0.17 from the Vala PPA, which you can add to your system as follows:

[ppa:vala-team/ppa [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~vala-team/+archive/ppa) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vala-team/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**On Ubuntu 12.10, you don't need to add any PPAs (Vala 0.17 is available in the valac-0.18 package in the official repositories).**

**On Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10, you can obtain the dependencies for Geary with these commands:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install valac-0.18 cmake libcanberra-dev libgee-dev libglib2.0-dev libgmime-2.6-dev \
       libgnome-keyring-dev libgtk-3-dev libnotify-dev libsqlite3-dev libunique-3.0-dev \
       libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev libindicate-dev libunity-dev
```

You should check that you are using the right version of valac with the command

```
valac --version:
```

Vala 0.17.4

The version number must be at least 0.17.4. If it reports an earlier version, run

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config valac
```

and select 0.18 there.

**To build:**

```
$ cd geary
$ ./configure
$ make
```

After building, Geary can be installed with:

```
$ sudo make install
```

and removed with:

```
$ sudo make uninstall
```

**Running**

Once compiled, Geary can be run straight from the build directory:

```
$ ./geary
```

It will prompt for a username and a password. Geary will then fetch all the account folders and load the most recent messages from the Inbox.

SOURCE -> improve format, step order and so on http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/geary/wiki

---

if you don't want to compile you can use  :

for ubuntu <= 12.04 , “Yorba” team

[ppa:yorba/ppa [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ppa) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

for ubuntu = 11.10, 12.04, 12.10 , “Yorba” team Daily Builds

[ppa:yorba/daily-builds [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/daily-builds) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

```
$ sudo apt-get install geary
```

Comment: YOU ARE THE REALLY EXPERT IN UBUNTU!Could you please have a look at this question [Unable to locate package lightread](http://http://askubuntu.com/questions/202064/unable-to-locate-package-lightread)  Thank you : )